# How to setup 6rd?

Tags: ipv6

How to setup 6rd on a Raspberry Pi? The ISP router doesn't have the option of it enabled and the other router I have doesn't really work behind NAT (just using it as an access point right now).

I've NAT enabled in my ISP router.

Comment: read https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1598